# Change the header of a specific column within several files that have the same data structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling to find a workable answer to this question, so I will not go in depth with what I've tried, but I'm basically trying to do the following:

1.) I have a folder with several .txt files with the same suffix (e.g. *.data.txt) with the dynamic part of the filename being the *

2.) Each file has the exact same data structure with the same number of columns and same header titles

3.) Given the 2 points above, I'd like to loop through each file, take one specific column with the header "average_depth" and generate a new dataframe with these columns joined together side-by-side with a new header title being the dynamic part of the file name (* from point #1)

Hopefully my goals here are straightforward, but I can clarify if necessary. I've scoured several sources on how to do this, and I figured it might be more effective to ask this directly. Thank you so much, I'm looking forward to testing out the responses I see here.

Comment: what is the structure of the file names? say, "xyz_1.data.txt" ?

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

collected_columns  = []
for file in glob.glob('/your/path/*.data.txt'):
    # read data
    df = pd.DataFrame.read_csv(file)
    # extract name
    id_ = file.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    # rename column
    df.rename({'average_depth': f'average_depth_{id_}'}, axis='columns')

    collected_columns.append(df[f'average_depth_{id_}'])

final_df = pd.concat(collected_columns, axis=1)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Max! I tried running this and just added one thing to keep the names intact: `df.rename({'average_depth': f'average_depth_{id_}'}, axis='columns', inplace=True,)`

many thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah yes, I just marked it as accepted. Sorry about that, I'm very new to all of this. You helped me out big time!! :) Thank you!